# Reducing the size of svg files

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I hope that I'm asking the right question at the related place.
I created a svg file in Illustration to use it as background. But my svg file had 800kb size. I removed some paths and then it came to 120kb. But it's larger than png file which I created the same background. I tried to minify the svg file and its lost some gradient and came to 70kb size. but it's still to big and png file has behalf of that size. What do I do to reduce the size of svg file till becomes to less than png file size.

Another help, can every body help me to customize jQuery library? because I just need the selector rules but I don't need animate or other related function. For example the only functions (Specially selector and css function)I need is in code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").hover(function()
    {$(this).siblings("*").css({"-webkit-filter": "opacity(30%)", "filter": "opacity(30%)"});
    }, function(){
        $(this).siblings("*").css({"-webkit-filter": "opacity(100%)", "filter": "opacity(100%)"});
    });
});
```

This is that I can't have it by css selector only. 
Please help me, if you can. Thank you so much.

Comment: This might help you out: http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/

Comment: The purpose of an SVG is not really to save file size - It's to be able to manipulate it without losing quality (resize, animate, stretch, etc.).  If you have a lot of paths and gradients, you're not going to reduce it below the size of a png file.  If you don't need to scale or animate points of an image, then use a PNG.

Comment: Zip the SVG file and serve it like that. UAs will automatically unzip it.